# Are Morrey spaces reflexive?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Since $L^{p,0}=L^p$ and $L^1$ is not reflexive, thus in general [Morrey space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morrey%E2%80%93Campanato_space) is not reflexive, but how about for $L^{p,\lambda}$ with $1<p<+\infty$ and $0<\lambda<n$, where $n$ is the dimension of domain.

What's more, it seems that the dual space for Morrey spaces are not clear so far?

Answer (score 1):

For any function space defined as "some supremum is finite" without further conditions like continuity or vanishing, you should expect that:
(a) the space is nonreflexive and nonseparable;
(b) its dual is too large to be described in concrete terms.

The reason for both things is that $\ell_\infty$ embeds into the space (recall that every subspace of a nonreflexive space must be nonreflexive). In case of Morrey spaces, take a well-separated sequence of balls $B_n$ with quickly decaying radii $r_n$, and define, for any sequence $c\in\ell_\infty$, 
$$f_c = \sum_n c_n r_n^{(\lambda-n)/p}\chi_{B_n}$$ 
This is constructed so that 
$$\|c\|_\infty\le \|f\|_{\lambda,p}\le K\|c\|_\infty$$
for some constant $K$.